# Index Error when using list comprehension on column in Pandas Dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, list-comprehension

I have a DataFrame with a column like this: 

     `Data Science Score
0    303231.0
1    238632.0
2    209423.0
3    207254.0
4    206395.0`

I am trying to split the elements in the series from the end after the character that corresponds to their index+1.

If I use `print()` with this for loop:

```
for x in df["Data Science Score"]:
    print(df["Data Science Score"][df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]].astype(str).rsplit(str(df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]+1),1)[0])
```

I get the desired output:

```
30323
23863
20942
20725
20639
```

However, if I actually want to create a new column by using the above code in a list comprehension or just using it to create a list via `.append()`, like so:

```
df["Data Science Score cleaned"]=[df["Data Science Score"][df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]].astype(str).rsplit(str(df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]+1),1)[0] for x in df["Data Science Score"]]
```

or so:

```
asas=[]
for x in df["Data Science Score"]:
    asas.append(df["Data Science Score"][df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]].astype(str).rsplit(str(df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]+1),1)[0])
```

I get the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
IndexError                                Traceback (most recent call   last)
<ipython-input-11-4f8f3d44b86b> in <module>()
----> 1 df["Data Science Score cleaned"]=[df["Data Science Score"]     [df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]].astype(str).rsplit(str(df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]+1),1)[0] for x in df["Data Science Score"]]

<ipython-input-11-4f8f3d44b86b> in <listcomp>(.0)
----> 1 df["Data Science Score cleaned"]=[df["Data Science Score"][df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]].astype(str).rsplit(str(df.index[df["Data Science Score"]== x][0]+1),1)[0] for x in df["Data Science Score"]]

 ~\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\indexes\base.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   1741 
   1742         if is_scalar(key):
-> 1743             return getitem(key)
   1744 
   1745         if isinstance(key, slice):

  IndexError: index 0 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 0
```

I don't really understand why it doesn't work when creating a list. Can someone explaing why, and how to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

If I correctly understand you want to convert the value in the cell to an int of length 5.

What about:

```
df['rounded_score'] = df['Data Science Score'].apply(lambda x: int(x / 10.0))
```

this approach should easier than coverting to string and split.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! However, that is only an example from the series. Originally, theses values are floating point numbers (varying in total length), with an added "rank" (e.g. 1,2 etc). The last digit is always the "ranking" displayed in the original source. Hence I am splitting the string after the number indicating the "rank" (e.g. 1 etc.)

I any case, I am really looking for some explanation for the behaviour described. Maybe it's because print() doesn't use a generator or smth? I am kind of lost here.

Comment: The error you see above is due to `[0]`, in your code you did this 3 times, my suggestion is to split your code in a more simple and debuggable format, it seems that your doing `[0]` on something that does not have it.

Comment: That was indeed the issue, I had 6 NaN at the bottom of the column. dropna() fixed this. The list comprehension works fine now. Thanks for pointing that out. I was kinda tunnelvisioned there I reckon. Kudos!